# R: Deleting rows from a data frame based on values of other vector

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame with baskets of products of purchases of individuals. A row stands for a basket of products of one individual. I want to remove all the rows (baskets) that contain a product (expressed as a integer) that are listed in a vector named products.to.delete . Here is a small image of how the data set looks like.

[image]

Next to that I have a vector containing a large number of numbers that must be deleted. I would like to delete all the rows that contain a value from this vector.

here is some code to make it reproducable:

```
    dataframe <- as.data.frame( matrix(data = sample(10000,1000,replace = TRUE),20,50))
 products.to.delete <- sample(10000,200,replace = FALSE)
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Could you `dput()` your dataframe inside your question and also add the vector in question in order to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is `data`, and your vector of target values is `vals`, you could do this:

```
data[apply(data,1,\(r) !any(r %in% vals)),]
```

That is, within each row of `data` (i.e. `apply(data,1...)`), you can check if any of the values are in `vals`. Reverse the boolean using `!`, to create an global logical vector for selecting the remaining rows

Answer (score 1):

For your next questions, please create reproducible examples such as the one below.

What you're after is called *filtering* and can be done in base R by the following.

First, create an object called for example `myfilter` which is a boolean vector  with the same length as the number of rows in your `data.frame`.

```
mydat <- data.frame("col1"=1:5, "col2"=letters[1:5])
  col1 col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3    c
4    4    d
5    5    e


myfilter <- mydat$col2 %in% c("a", "c")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
mydat[myfilter,]
col1 col2
1    1    a
3    3    c
```

Then simply include this object into brackets `[]`. R will keep rows where values are `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I edited my post to make it reproducable. One thing that is different from your answer is that I'm not looking at one column specifically like here ```mydat$col2``` but I want it to be over all the columns. Thank you so much